# How to search an Associative array if a value is between two elements

Tags: php, arrays, search, associative

I have the following:

I have a certain value 14.50

And the following associative array:

```
                  element a      element b        element c
row 1              8              12                house
row 2              12             15                cat
row 3              17             20                pizza
```

Does anybody know how I can check the associative array in which row the 14.50 is between element a & b. In the example row 2.

I want to get the value cat.
If the value would be 4 I want to give the first value ' house ' ...

Please advice :)

```
  Array
  (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [medewerker] => 799
              [datum] => 2016-04-14 00:00:00
              [uursoort] => Reisuur
              [uurcode] => RNV
              [project] => 
              [begin] => 7.50
              [eind] => 8.00
              [uren] => 0.5
              [cumulatiefOud] => 0
              [cumulatief] => 0
              [overuren125] => 0
              [overuren150] => 0
          )

      [1] => Array
          (
              [medewerker] => 799
              [datum] => 2016-04-14 00:00:00
              [uursoort] => Werkuur
              [uurcode] => DNV
              [project] => 
              [begin] => 8.00
              [eind] => 16
              [uren] => 8
              [cumulatiefOud] => 0
              [cumulatief] => 8
              [overuren125] => 0
              [overuren150] => 0
          )

      [2] => Array
          (
              [medewerker] => 799
              [datum] => 2016-04-14 00:00:00
              [uursoort] => Werkuur
              [uurcode] => DEV125
              [project] => 
              [begin] => 8.00
              [eind] => 16.25
              [uren] => 0.25
              [cumulatiefOud] => 8
              [cumulatief] => 8.25
              [overuren125] => 0.25
              [overuren150] => 0
          )
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the associative array, please?

Comment: see above.
So in this case where the value of lets say 7.75 is between the element 'BEGIN' and element 'Eind'... in this case the [1]

Comment: Er... There's no `CAT` in your code that you posted. `:(`

Comment: Can you try using `var_export` and get us the code please?

Comment: Array
  (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [medewerker] => 799
              [datum] => 2016-04-14 00:00:00
              [uursoort] => Reisuur
              [uurcode] => RNV
              [project] => 
              [begin] => 7.50
              [eind] => 8.00
              [uren] => 0.5
              [cumulatiefOud] => 0
              [cumulatief] => 0
              [overuren125] => 0
              [overuren150] => 0
          )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it worked:

```
<?php

$arr = array();
$arr[1]['a'] = 8;
$arr[1]['b'] = 12;
$arr[1]['c'] = 'house';
$arr[2]['a'] = 12;
$arr[2]['b'] = 15;
$arr[2]['c'] = 'cat';
$arr[3]['a'] = 17;
$arr[3]['b'] = 20;
$arr[3]['c'] = 'pizza';

$number = 14.5;
foreach($arr as $row)
{
    if ($number >= $row['a'] && $number <= $row['b'])
    echo $row['c'];
}

?>
```

> **Output:** cat

It's basic programming, actually. You just need to iterate trough the rows and verify if the number you desire is between the `begin` and `end` variables. In this case, `a` and `b`.

Then `echo` the value you want, or do something else.

In this code if `$number = 12;`, it would echo

> housecat

So you won't want to verify if it is bigger or equal, but instead just check if it is bigger and not equal `b`.

Like this:

```
if ($number > $row['a'] && $number <= $row['b'])
```

Comment: Yeah you are absolutely right. I was just off track there. 
          foreach ($rows as $rows5=> $value) {          
           $uursoort = $value['uursoort'];
           $project = $value['projectcode'];
           
           if ($uursoort === 'Reisuur') {

I did the same already multiple times. Dont know why I missed this one haha. Thanks Phiter.

Comment: @ESchumie, picking up an accepted answer may help the future users to have a guidance ;)

Comment: TRUE THAT. Thanks.

Comment: Just tick the little V near my answer if it helped you.

Comment: I did, better late then never ;)

Comment: Damn, 2016. It was on lunch break on my internship when I answered this. Boy do I miss that company.